# Can I open a bank account in the Netherlands using my workplace address?

Tags: netherlands, banking, arrival

I will start working in Rotterdam next month, but I will temporarily stay at an Airbnb room (for the first 3 weeks) while I search for an apartment.

However, I need to open a bank account but I will not have an official address to provide it.

Can I give the address of the company where I will be working?

Comment: Please add a comment to my answer after you've gone through with the process to report how it went!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do this *if and only if* you manage to obtain your [BSN number](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/other_subjects/citizen_service_number/what_is_a_citizen_service_number_bsn/) before having a fixed address.**

To open a bank account, you will be asked for a BSN number; and to get a BSN number you must register with the government using some address. Now, in some cases you are able to give your place of employment as a temporary address. This happened to me when I registered for a BSN, at the Amsterdam Expact Center (in 2015).

Anyway, in your case, I suggest to:

1. Ask your employer where other people have done this.
2. Failing to be informed by your employer, contact the phone or web support of the bank you're interested in (or of several banks), and ask them whether that's possible and at which branches
3. Failing to get an ok from them, ask them for the details of a branch which caters to expatriates specifically, if they have one; or their central branch in Rotterdam - and go there to try and open the account.

By the way, you might want to check out this [list of banks in the Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_banks_in_the_Netherlands) and decide which one you want to try, or again - ask for recommendations from co-workers or even your employer's HR staff.

**Edit:** OP reports in a comment he was unable to get a BSN with his workplace address. I'm not sure under which conditions doing so is possible.

Comment: So here's the feedback on my experience.To open a bank account I am required to have already a BSN number (social security), which by its turn requires me to register at the "city hall".I can only do this if I have an address already.I have to make proof of my address (with my rental agreement, for instance).So, I really had to have a home address, not my work address.However, after I open the bank account,it is possible for me to change the associated address to wherever I want (including of course my work address) at DigID website (centralized service where you can manage you personal info).

Comment: @cinico: Well, I got my BSN number using my work address, weeks before I found an apartment. But I'll make my answer more exact.

Comment: That I didn't know it was possible. If you can register at city hall with your work address, you can definitely open your bank account without having a home address. But I told (possibly wrong) that I had to give my home address for the BSN number. Thank you once again!